# iOS csv attachment to email

Tags: ios, email, csv, attachment, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I can successfully add an attachment to an email with my iOS app, but only if I hard code the file name, otherwise there is no data in the attachment.

This works:

```
(IBAction)sendEmail:(id)sender
{
transectNameString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"dipstransect"];
transectFileExt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".csv"];
NSString *string1 = transectNameString;
NSString *string2 = @" Drops";
NSString *string3 = transectFileExt;
NSString *tempstring1 = [string1 stringByAppendingString:string2];
setTransectName = [tempstring1 stringByAppendingString:string3];

MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer;
NSArray *emailAddresses;

mailComposer = [MFMailComposeViewController new];
emailAddresses = @[];
mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mailComposer setToRecipients:emailAddresses];

filePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
fileName = @"Paynes Drops.csv";
fileAtPath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileAtPath];

[mailComposer addAttachmentData:fileData mimeType:@"text/csv" fileName:fileName];

[self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

This does not work:

```
(IBAction)sendEmail:(id)sender
{
transectNameString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"dipstransect"];
transectFileExt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".csv"];
NSString *string1 = transectNameString;
NSString *string2 = @" Drops";
NSString *string3 = transectFileExt;
NSString *tempstring1 = [string1 stringByAppendingString:string2];
setTransectName = [tempstring1 stringByAppendingString:string3];

MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer;
NSArray *emailAddresses;

mailComposer = [MFMailComposeViewController new];
emailAddresses = @[];
mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mailComposer setToRecipients:emailAddresses];

filePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
fileName = setTransectName;
fileAtPath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileAtPath];

[mailComposer addAttachmentData:fileData mimeType:@"text/csv" fileName:fileName];

[self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

What is it about the fileName that causes the problem?

Comment: Have you debugged the code at all? Verify that your code to build `setTrasectName` is working as you expect.

Comment: I solved the problem by moving the NSUserDeafaults statement to ViewDidLoad, and thereafter everything worked as it should.

Comment: if you solved it you should post your own answer so the question is marked resolved

Answer (score 0):

I moved the following line to the ViewDidLoad statement and it worked.

- (void)viewDidLoad
  {

  transectNameString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"dipstransect"];

  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  }
- (IBAction)sendEmail:(id)sender
  {

  MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer;
  NSArray *emailAddresses;

  mailComposer = [MFMailComposeViewController new];
  emailAddresses = @[];
  mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
  [mailComposer setToRecipients:emailAddresses];

  filePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

  transectFileExt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".csv"];
  NSString *string2 = @" Drops";

  NSString *tempString1 = [transectNameString stringByAppendingString:string2];
  NSString *tempString2 = [tempString1 stringByAppendingString:transectFileExt];

  fileName = tempString2;
  fileAtPath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
  NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileAtPath];

  [mailComposer addAttachmentData:fileData mimeType:@"text/csv" fileName:fileName];

  transectFile2Ext = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".txt"];
  NSString *string4 = @" Drops Notes";

  NSString *tempString3 = [transectNameString stringByAppendingString:string4];
  NSString *tempString4 = [tempString3 stringByAppendingString:transectFile2Ext];

  file2Name = tempString4;
  file2AtPath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:file2Name];
  NSData *file2Data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:file2AtPath];

  [mailComposer addAttachmentData:file2Data mimeType:@"text/txt" fileName:file2Name];

  [self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];

}